# Without resizing div but user body overflow(x and y) to browse the element when browser is not a full screen

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image: PIC1]

I want to design two vertical divs in the same row without changing the height and the width of divs when the browser is not a full screen. And the user can use the body (overflow scroll) to turn x and y-axis to keep reading that two DIVs elements,

[image: PIC2]

but I have no idea to set it( I have tried float[left /right]).

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
<div style="display:flex;">
    <div style="min-width:50%;height:100%;border:solid silver 1px;">LeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeft.......repeat.....</div>
    <div style="min-width:50%;height:100%;border:solid silver 1px;">RightRightRight.....repeat.......</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any starting code?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support very old browsers ( check https://caniuse.com/#search=flex ), then I suggest you use tables. Floats may also work if you can fix the width of the container. Otherwise, go with table.

```html
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    .holder {
        display:flex;
    }
    .holder>* {
        flex-shrink:0;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        border:solid 1px silver;
        width:50%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
<div class="holder">
    <div>Left</div>
    <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to change the min-width as 50%, however, overflow occurs. Also, "Left" text is out of the border and overlaps the right div. Then, how can the element inside div be restircted not to outside the border?

And how to set the height of the div(left / right) as full / 100%?
Thanks

Comment: You should update your question to include EVERYTHING you want to achieve, not keep adding questions to the question without any code example or clear requirements.

Comment: Check out snippet; you need to use box-sizing to include border in measurements.

Answer (score 0):

What about using display:flex in the body-tag - or better in a div container?

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
<div style="min-width:400px;height:400px;border:solid silver 1px;">Left</div>
<div style="min-width:400px;height:400px;border:solid silver 1px;">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to change the min-width as 50%, however, overflow occurs. Also, "Left" text is out of the border and overlaps the right div. Then, how can the element inside div be restircted not to outside the border?

And how to set the height of the div(left / right) as full / 100%?
Thanks

Comment: If you want your divs at 100% of screen size, you have to set each div to 100%, the height of the container div to 100% and the height of the html- and the body-tag to 100%. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for 2 divs in a row with overflow set to scroll with a set height of 200px and a width of 50%.

for the php / html use this

```
<div class="main">
<div class="left scroll">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div class="right scroll">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

and for the css try this

```
.main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.left{
    background-color: red;
}
.right{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.scroll{
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}
```